# pacstrap refuses existing directory

Tags: arch-linux, zfs

I want to install archlinux with a ZFS root.

`pacstrap` refuses to work because `/mnt/var/mail` already exists (because I want a dedicated zfs volume for this directory).

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the answer, /var/mail is supposed to be a link and not a directory.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  5 20:17 /var/mail -> spool/mail
```